# PHP Security (strip_tags, htmlentities)

Tags: php, security, strip-tags, stripslashes

I'm working in a personal project and besides using prepared statements, I would like to use every input as threat. For that I made a simple function.

```
function clean($input){
if (is_array($input)){
    foreach ($input as $key => $val){
        $output[$key] = clean($val);
    }
}else{
    $output = (string) $input;
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $output = stripslashes($output);
    }
    $output = htmlentities($output, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

}
return $output;
}
```

Is this enought or should I use to the following code?

```
        $output = mysqli_real_escape_string($base, $input);
        $output = strip_tags($output);
```

Sorry this could be a silly question but I would like to avoid any problem with me code :)
Thanks for your help

Comment: Using Prepared Statements is secure enough and don't require you to escape your data in any way. Escaping is only necessary when you're concatenating your SQL queries with the input data, which isn't the case when using Prepared Statements.

Comment: The DBMS will automatically sanitise the parameters provided in a prepared statement based on the expected data type and encoding. If you are manually escaping the string and then sending it as a prepared statement parameter you're actually making it less secure.

Comment: If you have the time, learn to use `PDO` to handle your database interactions. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Escaping should always be *for a particular context* - the operations needed to make something safe for use in a database could make it unsafe for use as output. So never, ever, write a generic `clean` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I applaud your efforts.
You must, friendly community member, consider decoupling your operations.

**1**) Have one function/routine/class/method for filtering input (`filter_input_array()`, `strip_tags()`, `str_ireplace()`, `trim()`, etc ...). You may want to create functions that use loops to do filtering. Tricks such as double encoding, one-time-strip-spoofing, and more can defeat single usage of things like `strip_tags()`.

Here is a `strip_tags()` wrapper method from my `Sanitizer` class.
Notice how it compares the old value to the new value to see if they are equal. If they are not equal, it keeps on using `strip_tags()`. Although, there is quite of bit of preliminary INPUT_POST / $_POST checking done before this method is executed. Another version of this using `trim()` is actually executed before this one.

```
private function removeHtml(&$value)
{    
    if (is_scalar($value)) {
        do {
            $old = $value;
            $value = strip_tags($value);

            if ($value === $old) {
                break;
            }
        } while(1);
    } else if (is_array($value) && !empty($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $field => &$string) {
            do {
                $old = $string;
                $string = strip_tags($string);

                if ($string === $old) {
                    break;
                }
            } while (1);
        }
    } else {
       throw new Exception('The data being HTML sanitized is neither scalar nor in an array.');
    }

    return;
}
```

**2**) Have another one for validating input (`filter_var_array()`, `preg_match()`, `mb_strlen`, etc...)

Then, when your data needs to switch contexts ...

**A**) For databases, use prepared statements (`PDO`, preferably).

**B**) For returning / transmitting **user input** to the browser, escape the output with `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars` accordingly.

In terms of magic quotes, the best thing to do is just disable that in the `php.ini`.

Now, with those various constructs having their own areas of responsibility, all you have to do is manage the flow of logic and data inside of your handler file. This includes providing error messages to the user (when necessary) and handling errors/exceptions.

There is no need to use `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars` immediately if the data is going from the HTML form directly into the database. The point of escaping data is to prevent it from being interpreted as executable instructions inside a new context. There is no danger `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars` can resolve when passing data to a SQL query engine (that is why you filter and validate the input, and use (`PDO`) prepared statements).

However, after the data ***is retrieved from*** database tables *and* is *directly destined* for the browser, ok, now use `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars`. Create a `function` that uses a `for` or `foreach` loop to handle that scenario.

Here is a snippet from my `Escaper` class

```
public function superHtmlSpecialChars($html)
{
     return htmlspecialchars($html, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8', false);
}

public function superHtmlEntities(&$html)
{
    $html = htmlentities($html, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8', false);
}

public function htmlSpecialCharsArray(array &$html)
{       
    foreach ($html as &$value) {
        $value = $this->superHtmlSpecialChars($value);
    }

    unset($value);
}

public function htmlEntitiesArray(array &$html)
{       
    foreach ($html as &$value) {
        $this->superHtmlEntities($value);
    }

    unset($value);
}
```

You'll have to tailor your code to your own personal tastes and situation.

Note, if you plan on processing the data before sending it to the browser, do the processing first, then escape with your handy-dandy `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars` looping function.

You can do it!

Comment: This is a great answer. I think the first sentence should be worded more strongly: you *must* decouple your operations, because they *must* happen in different places in order to fulfill their purposes. As for magic quotes, the [last version of PHP to support them](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) was 5.3, *which stopped receiving official security patches [more than 2.5 years ago](http://php.net/eol.php)*.

Comment: @IMSoP Thank you. I remember starting out and having to study information security. Knowing *why* you are doing something (filter/validating/escaping) matters a lot.

Comment: Amazing answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usage scenario for both `strip_tags() and htmlentities or htmlspecialchars().`

1.) If you want to strip off any html elements from may be form input that may be vulnerable to XSS Attack, then use
`strip_tags()` function before making insertion to database
Example

```
$data= strip_tags('<b>Hello</b>');
```

Your output will be "Hello" and that is what to be passed to the server.

2.) If you want to print data to the browser or screen you can use `htmlentities() or htmlspecialchars()`
below is a used scenario where it can be used.

```
//DB PDO Connect....
$result2 = $db->prepare('select * from users where uid=:uid');
        $result2->execute(array(':uid' =>'1'));

 while ($row = $result2->fetch()) {


$pic=htmlentities($row['profilepic'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
}
```

You can then print $pic anywhere you want and be free from XSS Attack....