# Form with Post Method wont send information

Tags: php, html, post, xampp

I'm writing a simple HTML/PHP site and I'm sending information from a form with post method, but it wont work
My HTML code form the first page is:

```
    <div id="registrati">
    <section id="main">
        <h2 class="title">Per Registrarti completa questi form</h2>
        <form name="reg" method="post" onsubmit='return Control()'  action="Server_Add_User.php" > <!--provarlo su un pc senza problemi di xampp tutti i post vanno così-->
            <p>Sesso <input type="radio" name="sesso" value="m" checked="checked"> Uomo
            <input type="radio" name="sesso" value="f"> Donna
            <p>Nome: <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Inserisci nome"></p>
            <p>Cognome: <input name="cognome" type="text"  placeholder="Inserisci cognome"></p>
            <p>Data di nascita (formato GG/MM/AAAA): <input type="text" name="data" placeholder="Inserisci Data di nascita"></p>
            <p>Luogo di nascita: <input type="text" name="luogo" placeholder="Citt&agrave di nascita"></p>
            <p>Nazionalit&agrave: <input type="text" name="nazionalita" placeholder="Nazionalit&agrave"></p>
            <p>Telefono: <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo numero"></p>
            <p>Indirizzo: <input type="text" name="indirizzo" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo indirizzo"> </p>
            <p>Mail: <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Inserisci mail"></p>
            <p>Password: <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Inserisci password"></p>
            <p>Ripeti Password: <input type="password"  name="pwd2" placeholder="Ripeti password"></p>

</div>

<div id="pagamento">
    <section id="main">
        <h2 class="title">Inserisci i dati di pagamento</h2>
            <p>Tipo di carta: <input type="text" name="tipo" placeholder="Visa, MasterCard, ..." size="20"></p>
            <p>Numero Carta: <input type="text" name="numero" placeholder="Numero Carta" size="20"></p>
            <p>Nome Titolare: <input type="text" name="nome_t" placeholder="Nome del titolare" size="20"></p>
            <p>Cognome Titolare: <input type="text" name="cognome_t" placeholder="Cognome del titolare" size="20"></p>
            <p>Data di scadenza: <input type="text" name="data_s" placeholder="MM/AA" size="20"></p>
            <p>Codice Segreto: <input type="text"  name="code_s" placeholder="Codice a 3 cifre" ></p>
            <p> <a href='ToS.php'><h3>Accetto i Termini di Utilizzo</a> <input type="checkbox" name="term"></p></h3>
            <br>
            <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Completato" style="height:50px; width: 400px">
        </form>
        <br>
    </section>

</div>
```

Then in the Server_add_User.php

```
    <?php
    include 'Function.php';
    //checkifcookie();
    //goToHTTPS();

    if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $mail = htmlentities($_POST["mail"]);
    $pwd = htmlentities($_POST["pwd"]);
    $nome = htmlentities($_POST["nome"]);
    $cognome= htmlentities($_POST["cognome"]);
    $data= htmlentities($_POST["data"]);
    $luogo= htmlentities($_POST["luogo"]);
    $nazionalita= htmlentities($_POST["nazionalita"]);
    $telefono= htmlentities($_POST["telefono"]);
    $indirizzo= htmlentities($_POST["indirizzo"]);
    $tipo= htmlentities($_POST["tipo"]);
    $numero= htmlentities($_POST["numero"]);
    $nome_t= htmlentities($_POST["nome_t"]);
    $cognome_t= htmlentities($_POST["cognome_t"]);
    $data_s= htmlentities($_POST["data_s"]);
    $code_s= htmlentities($_POST["code_s"]);
    $sesso= htmlentities($_POST["sesso"]);
    $error = '0';


    if ($pwd !="" && $mail !="" && $nome!="" && $cognome !="" && $data!="" && $luogo !="" && $nazionalita !="" && $telefono !="" && $indirizzo !="" && $tipo !="" && $numero!="" && $nome_t!="" &&
        $cognome!="" && $data_s!="" && $code_s!="")
    {

        $error = addUser($sesso,$nome,$cognome,$data,$nazionalita,$telefono,$mail, $pwd,$tipo,$numero,$nome_t,$cognome_t,$data_s,$code_s,$luogo,$indirizzo);

         if($error=='0')
         {
             session_start();
             control_session($mail);
             $_SESSION['mail']=$mail;

                    header("refresh:3;url=index.php");
         }
        else{
            $error = "Ci sono problemi con il server";
            header("refresh:3;url=Forza_Registrazione_C.php");
            }
    }
    else
    {
        $error = "I dati inseriti non sono validi ";
        header("refresh:2;url=Forza_Registrazione_C.php");
    }
}


    else 
    {
        $error = print_r($_POST);

    }


?>
```

for my server the $_POST var is empty and it goes directly to the last else and print Array()

With Get method it works.
My XAMPP configuration is Apache: 443, 8080 -> maybe is 8080 the problem?
thanks

Ps: I can use only PHP/HTML/JS and no other language,
I tried some solution like id tag but it wont work anyway.

Comment: check for errors with error reporting; you have some.

Comment: I whipped up an answer you can use now and into the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Start with good HTML stucture, syntax, and semantics.

Use **HTML5** if you can.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   <!-- Add attributes as appropriate. -->
      <head>
          <title>My Registration Form</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
</html>
```

The section, `<section id="main">` is missing its closing tag.  The `<form>` `name="reg"` is missing it's closing tag. You should not close HTML tags out of order. I see a closing form tag in section `main`, but that is malformed. Also, I suggest using the `<label>` tag instead of paragraph tags (`<p>`) to label your `<input>` tags. When you are ready, try to use the CSS `margin` property to make space between HTML elements instead of inserting hard breaks (`<br>`). If you are collecting email addresses and telephone numbers, remember, there are `<input type="email">` and `<input type="tel">`.

If you really need *one form*, distributed over *two sections*. do this instead.

```
<div id="registrati">
    <section id="main">
        <h2 class="title">Per Registrarti completa questi form</h2>
        <form name="reg" onsubmit='return Control()' method="post" action="Server_Add_User.php">
            <label for"foo"><input id="foo" name="foo" type="text" value=""></label>
            <!-- Add various input controls with labels. -->

            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="89838374uidhyuifuih389ihfujf">
            <!-- Learn to implement a CSRF token! -->
        </form>
    </section>
</div>
```

Now use the [`form`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp) attribute for the rest of the controls

```
<div id="pagamento">
    <section id="main">
        <h2 class="title">Inserisci i dati di pagamento</h2>
        <label for="tipo">Tipo di carta: <input id="tipo" type="text" form="reg" name="tipo" placeholder="Visa, MasterCard, ..." size="20"></label>
        <!-- Add various input controls with labels. -->
    </section>
</div>
```

Additionally, you will want to have every form have its own token to deter cross-site request forgery attacks. Use a hashing function to generate the `value` for the token. Do not use the **MD5** or **SHA-1** hashing algorithms. Use at least SHA-2, Blowfish, or something with at least 256 - 512 bits. Use what you can learn to use.

### JavaScript (Behavior)

Having addressed some of the structural issues, we now move to the behavioral ones.

`onsubmit='return Control()'`

My suggestion to you is to remove this from your `<form>` tag, then see if the `$_POST` superglobal is empty. If everything works (after having made the changes above), re-apply the event handler. If submitting the form fails, work on your JavaScript. :-)

### PHP: [Filter, Validate,](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) and use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) Prepared Statements.

You do not need to do this to send data to your database.

```
$mail = htmlentities($_POST["mail"]);
```

HTML escaping functions are usually used as a counter-measure against cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks. They are used ***when user generated input is transmitted back to the browser***. Since the data is going into your database, there is no need to use `htmlentites()` at this time.

Do this at least (even though doing it this way has its limitations, and is not secure in and of itself).

```
$mail = htmlentities(trim(strip_tags(trim(strip_tags(trim($_POST["mail"]))))));
```

Also, you might want to consider using `mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8')` to determine how large the data is that you are working with.

```
if(mb_strlen($mail, 'UTF-8') <= 254)
{
    //etc ..., but you would want to define this in one place, like in a class method, or function.
}
```

You could also count the number of successful controls to make sure at least a minimum number is submitted each time. On top of that, you could define an array with the correct control names. Then, using a loop, you could ensure the controls submitted are the correct ones. After all, why continue processing if a) the minimum number of correct number of controls has not been met, or b) the correct controls have not been submitted. In that regard, let me introduce you to my friend [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Read my answer to this question for more information.

[Basic PHP Security Stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330228/php-security-strip-tags-htmlentities/42331473#42331473)

Now, as for your test to ensure that certain fields are not equal to the empty string, that is a good thing to do, but perhaps you could make a [user defined function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) out of this process. Have the function return `true` or `false`, or simply return the results of your super duper compound `AND` conditional. :-) You could still do more checking, but you'll get there eventually.

Lastly, to help deter ***SQL injection attacks***, use PDO prepared statements to send user data to your database. Learn how to use PDO. You will be glad you did, because `htmlentites()` is not helping you in regards to sending user input to your database.

### Sessions

Be careful about using the same session id for each return to the server. Learn about session fixation and implement [`session_regenerate_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php).
Generally, it is usually called after `session_start()`, like this

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
```

But, you can use some decision logic to improve this way of operating.

```
    if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    } elseif (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
        session_start();
        session_regenerate_id();
    } else {
        throw new \RuntimeException('The PHP session did not start.');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i correct my code but it wont work anyway.
The problem is XAMPP port, i tried on another computer with XAMPP default configuration and it works. I don't why port 8080 doesn't work.

Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

You use Control Function that I can't see definition of this!but if control return true form submitted correctly! 
So change your question and give us more information that I change my answer

Comment: Control(), js function, check only if the forms are well written, If not a pop up is shown. Maybe i should add a return True If all the checks are passed?

Comment: Yes! try this @Kalos92

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is not right. So your request is not actually sending. I used a code editor to find and fix the issues. Assuming your sending and validating register and payment data in one form. Please see the difference yourself.

```
<form name="reg" method="post" onsubmit='return Control()' action="Server_Add_User.php"> <!--provarlo su un pc senza problemi di xampp tutti i post vanno così-->
<div id="registrati">
    <section id="main">
        <h2 class="title">Per Registrarti completa questi form</h2>

            <p>Sesso <input type="radio" name="sesso" value="m" checked="checked"> Uomo
                <input type="radio" name="sesso" value="f"> Donna
            <p>Nome: <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Inserisci nome"></p>
            <p>Cognome: <input name="cognome" type="text" placeholder="Inserisci cognome"></p>
            <p>Data di nascita (formato GG/MM/AAAA): <input type="text" name="data" placeholder="Inserisci Data di nascita"></p>
            <p>Luogo di nascita: <input type="text" name="luogo" placeholder="Citt&agrave di nascita"></p>
            <p>Nazionalit&agrave: <input type="text" name="nazionalita" placeholder="Nazionalit&agrave"></p>
            <p>Telefono: <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo numero"></p>
            <p>Indirizzo: <input type="text" name="indirizzo" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo indirizzo"></p>
            <p>Mail: <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Inserisci mail"></p>
            <p>Password: <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Inserisci password"></p>
            <p>Ripeti Password: <input type="password" name="pwd2" placeholder="Ripeti password"></p>

    </section>
</div>

<div id="pagamento">
    <section id="main">
        <h2 class="title">Inserisci i dati di pagamento</h2>
        <p>Tipo di carta: <input type="text" name="tipo" placeholder="Visa, MasterCard, ..." size="20"></p>
        <p>Numero Carta: <input type="text" name="numero" placeholder="Numero Carta" size="20"></p>
        <p>Nome Titolare: <input type="text" name="nome_t" placeholder="Nome del titolare" size="20"></p>
        <p>Cognome Titolare: <input type="text" name="cognome_t" placeholder="Cognome del titolare" size="20"></p>
        <p>Data di scadenza: <input type="text" name="data_s" placeholder="MM/AA" size="20"></p>
        <p>Codice Segreto: <input type="text" name="code_s" placeholder="Codice a 3 cifre"></p>
        <p><a href='ToS.php'><h3>Accetto i Termini di Utilizzo</h3></a> <input type="checkbox" name="term"></p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Completato" style="height:50px; width: 400px">
    </section>
</div>
</form>
```